# How to access PDO object in class?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to build a simple database class. Within the constructor, I am initializing a PDO connection to my MySQL database. I am assigning this connection to a private variable in the database class. I then want to access that variable from a public function in the same class to query the database. Unfortunately, I keep getting an error as follows:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object.`

Below is my code for the Database class I am using:

```
class Database{
    private $conn;

    private function __contruct(){
        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'username', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage()."<br/>";
            die();
        }
    }

    public function query($q){
        $query = $this->conn->prepare($q);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

I then have the following code to utilize this class.

```
$db = new Database();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM FOO");
```

Any suggestions for the cause of the error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo in `function __contruct()`. It never gets called automatically.

Comment: PHP doesn't know how to "contruct"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your constructor:

1. It's misspelled: `__contruct()` should be `__construct()`
2. It's private, so you won't be able to instantiate it from outside the class.

#2 isn't necessarily a problem, but you'll need a static method to do anything with it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error. I changed both things and it now works.